# XTEXT web editor - custom highlighting in Eclipse Ace

Tags: web, editor, highlight, xtext, ace-editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjNFM.png)

I need guidance about how to use custom highlighting in xtext web editor. I am using eclipse Ace for this.

Actually, I need to highlight or change color of the text where user enters duplicate names.

## Regards.

Define Top-Package {

```
}


Define Timing {
    UUID: "hello"
    SHORT-NAME: "xecutionTiming"
    CATEGORY: ""
    NAME: "iram"
    TRACEABLE-SPECIFICATION-REFS: ""
    Define Constraints {
            Define Execution-Time-Constraint {
            UUID: ""
            SHORT-NAME: "WiperCtrlBasic"
            CATEGORY: ""
            NAME: "rida"
            RESUME-REFS: ""
            PREEMPTION-REFS: ""
            START: ""
            STOP: ""
            }   
        Define Execution-Time-Constraint {
            UUID: ""
            SHORT-NAME: "WiperCtrlBasic"
            CATEGORY: ""
            NAME: "misbah"
            RESUME-REFS: ""
            PREEMPTION-REFS: ""
            START: ""
            STOP: ""
            }
        Define Execution-Time-Constraint {
            UUID: ""
            SHORT-NAME: "WiperCtrlBasic"
            CATEGORY: ""
            NAME: "iram"
            RESUME-REFS: ""
            PREEMPTION-REFS: ""
            START: ""
            STOP: ""
            }       
    
        }
     }      
}  

 }
```

Comment: according to https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/330_web_support.html semantic highlighting is not supported in ace.

Comment: This scenario is not possible? example: Person: John ...... here "Person:" is a keyword but I want to change color of "John" (based on some condition i.e. if John appears more than once)

Comment: at least the table says no. not with ace.

Comment: any workaround?

Comment: why not use a normal validation?

Comment: Any tutorial? Please comment on this? https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-web/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext.web/src/main/java/org/eclipse/xtext/web/server/syntaxcoloring/HighlightingResult.java

Comment: simply implement a normal check https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/103_domainmodelnextsteps.html#tutorial-validation

Comment: and again: table says: highlighting works in Orion and CodeMirror but NOT in ACE

Comment: Yes, I already saw this limitation in the table. Let me try your example and then will come back.

Comment: hi, I tried validation. It works fine with capital first letter but unique name is confusing to implement. Please see snippet of my DSL. I want to implement unique name of each constraint defined under Reaction_Constraint. please guide. Regards.

Comment: i dont understand where the problem is implementing that validation, can you elaborate. write a check for the root or the element wherein you want uniquness of the model, traverse the ast, find duplicates, mark them.

Comment: Please see the error in image (I have updated the post).

Comment: sorry. this is a normal java error that should be clear. you try to iterate over something that is not a list. from the screenshot its unclear what you actually want to do.

Comment: so i would have expected a `for (Execution_Time_Constraint c : superEntity){...}`

Comment: oky that java error is solved. Thanks.

Comment: however, what I wanna achieve is still not done. I want to capture duplicate constraint names. as shared in xtext validation code that duplicate feature names are captured

Comment: Please see new image. The code gives error when names are even different. please guide.

Comment: can you please provide a reproducing example incl unit test. i e.g. miss a filter for the object you are checking. (e.g. etc != other)

Comment: I have little trace... etc.getName(): abb, other.getName(): abb ...... however i dont have two  similar names in constraints

Comment: yes but you may compare the same eobject as etc and as other. so i miss an `&& etc != other`

Comment: adding "&& etc != other" resulted in infinite loop :/

Comment: this is impossible. if you add it to the while instead of the if?!?. please again: provide a gitlab/github/.... reproducer with a unit test.

Comment: when I added "&& etc != ExecutionConstraints.get(i)" in while then it gave error on all except first.

Comment: please see github: https://github.com/MisbahAwan/xtextWebValidationError

Comment: I have updated the above post and provided the runtime instance there. please ignore other grammar errors and see the validation stuff i have posed above as picture as well.

Comment: also please see above attached image. thanks

Comment: again: i cannot find a unit test there. thus i cannot simply run it to reprodcue. and: the `&& etc != other` should go to the if not the while. this is normal java programming and not related to emf or xtext at all.

Answer (score 0):

The intended "vanilla Ace" way of doing validation is to either use workers (e.g. see [javascript_worker.js](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/mode/javascript_worker.js)), or do it yourself whenever you want it.

Ace doesn't have semantic syntax highlighting in the same way VS Code does, but you can use `editor.session.setAnnotations` to add colored backgrounds behind tokens if you want.